# Adding --record=true on a deployment file - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I'm new to Kubernetes and I wanted to know if there is there a way I can add '--record=true' inside the deployment yaml file, so I do not have to type it on the command line!

I know it goes like this: kubectl apply -f deployfile.yml --record

I am asking this because we work on a team, and not everyone is using --record=true at the end of the command when deploying files to kubernetes!

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no feature like `--record=true` flag in `kubectl` that you can add to `Manifest`.

The command which was used to start the `Deployment` is being stored in the `kubernetes.io/change-cause` annotation. This is being used for Rollout history which is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment).

> First, check the revisions of this Deployment:
>
> `kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment`
>   The output is similar to this:

```
deployments "nginx-deployment"
REVISION    CHANGE-CAUSE
1           kubectl apply --filename=https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml --record=true
2           kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1 --record=true
3           kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.91 --record=true
```

> `CHANGE-CAUSE` is copied from the Deployment annotation `kubernetes.io/change-cause` to its revisions upon creation. You can specify the `CHANGE-CAUSE` message by:
>
> - Annotating the Deployment with `kubectl annotate deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment kubernetes.io/change-cause="image updated to 1.9.1"`
> - Append the `--record` flag to save the `kubectl` command that is making changes to the resource.
> - Manually editing the manifest of the resource.
>
> To see the details of each revision, run:
>   `kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment --revision=2`
>
> The output is similar to this:

```
deployments "nginx-deployment" revision 2
  Labels:       app=nginx
          pod-template-hash=1159050644
  Annotations:  kubernetes.io/change-cause=kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1 --record=true
  Containers:
   nginx:
    Image:      nginx:1.9.1
    Port:       80/TCP
     QoS Tier:
        cpu:      BestEffort
        memory:   BestEffort
    Environment Variables:      <none>
  No volumes.
```

For the command history I would use `$ history` or check user bash_history

`$ tail /home/username/.bash_history`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias in your bashrc or zshrc as below

`alias kubectl=kubectl --record` and then do `kubectl apply -f deployfile.yml`

or

`alias kr=kubectl --record` and `kr apply -f deployfile.yml`